# German games for dyslexic to learn language

Tags: learning

My son (8) has dyslexia and we need to motivate him a lot to read and write.
He is German and German is his mother tongue. (But German is not my mother tongue.)

I learned a lot of English playing some kind of adventure game where I should interact with the figures writing simple questions and answers. I would sit there with a dictionary and look up all the words I didn't know — something I otherwise would never do.

Do you know any games like that in German?
Or other games which are so exciting to play that you forget the educational part while playing?

We already have some games specially designed for kids with dyslexia, but the game play is so boring that it's hard to keep up the motivation.

Comment: This feels like a good community wiki. Especially seeing that _some_ regulars are feeling unworthy of posting their recommendations as answers again...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you check out [Adlung Games](http://www.adlung-spiele.de), a small independent board game studio that focuses exclusively on card games.

They developed many of their games together with professional educators, therapists, teachers etc., and do a lot of testing with their "target demographic group" - but always with the focus of "must be fun", never the "obvious training disguised as game" most children can spot from afar.

Some of their games are explicitly for speech-/language training and encourage lateral thinking, *but I am not sure whether they offer something explicitly for dyslexia.*
They are very nice, it might be well worth writing them an e-mail and simply ask. Sometimes they have variable rules for their games to fit different requirements as well, iirc.

(And the games aren't expensive either - well under 10€ each, so no breaking the budget to give it a try.)

---

Disclaimer:
No affilliation, just a happy customer/player for well over a decade.

Answer (score 1):

Day of the Tentacle:
it is an old dos game with funny comic characters and uses multiple choice answers to move from scene to scene. But you have to turn of the sound. Your kid has all the time of the world, to read the lines but you have to have patience and help a little. Have done the game with a dyslexic child and it worked. But it is easier to help if know the solution. game is nonviolent and very funny.
good luck